# How to resolve a javascript error on bxgallery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Demo on this link :
https://jsfiddle.net/oitsuki/khe0xmh3/

I have a problem, bxgallery doesn't want to create a litle image.

The console say : `$orig.find(...).size` is not a function
the problem come from line 50 :

```
var k = $orig.find('img').size();
```

How to resolve this pb :
Note : I use the latest jquery and boostrap 4

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

That is because version 3 of jquery (*you mentioned you use the latest*) has removed the `.size()` method.

See https://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/3.0/#breaking-change-deprecated-size-removed

---

Change the error code to

```
var k = $orig.find('img').length;
```

or use a 2.x version of jQuery

Comment: @Amy works fine for me, once you include jQuery and call the bxGallery after the plugin is loaded. See https://jsfiddle.net/khe0xmh3/5/